# Running d3 javascript within java

Tags: java, javascript, svg, d3.js

I have this project that requires rendering `javascript` on the server side within `java`.

basically what I want to do is to transform the javascript code into a `svg` tag that I can later directly added it to my `HTML`.

to demonstrate I gonna use a simple example from :

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6216797.

this is my `java` code :

```
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
    Bindings bindings = js.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    bindings.put("stdout", System.out);
    System.out.println(
    js.eval(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("d3Example.js")))
    );
  }
```

the d3Example.js is :

```
var require = (function () {
var _required = {};
return (function (url, callback) {
    if (typeof url == 'object') {
        // We've (hopefully) got an array: time to chain!
        if (url.length > 1) {
            // Load the nth file as soon as everything up to the
            // n-1th one is done.
            require(url.slice(0,url.length-1), function () {
                require(url[url.length-1], callback);
            });
        } else if (url.length == 1) {
            require(url[0], callback);
        }
        return;
    }
});
})();


require(['d3.v3.min.js'], function () {
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.transform({
  point: function(px, py) { this.stream.point(x(px), y(py)); }
});

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("geo.json", function(error, geo) {
  x.domain(d3.extent(geo.features, function(d) { return d.properties.Easting; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(geo.features, function(d) { return d.properties.Northing; }));

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(geo)
      .attr("class", "lot")
      .attr("d", path);
});


});
```

my desired output should be the html code that creates the picture as in : 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6216797

the idea of this project is to be able to do the `javascript` computation on the server side and the client only receives the `svg` tag that is rendered by html to create a nice graphics.

Comment: Could you explain your reasoning for doing it server side and whether you're restricted to Java?

Comment: @George you'll probably laugh, but our studies showed, that our clients are too lazy and don't like to click on the links given. so we try to create the html  and/or a pdf out of it and send them the actual file.

Comment: System call to `phantom.js` and you are done. It'll can even spit out a nice paginated PDF for you.

Answer (score 2):

So one possibility is to use nodejs to run your javascript on server side https://mango-is.com/blog/engineering/pre-render-d3-js-charts-at-server-side/

generate the html and then save it to file. Now using whichever language you prefer, you could convert said html to a pdf if you prefer and then offer up this file as a download.

Another option may be to use Apache Wicket, which is a java based web front end tool. It's capable of generating the html and javascript page. Though I haven't looked into how to get that page to a file.
http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/

Comment: many thanks.  all our servers/projects are java oriented. I'm trying to keep it that why. however this will be my last resource.

Comment: the second option might be useful, needs some looking into though

Comment: if you are considering Apache Wicket, take a look at Vaadin too (its based on GWT)